# Font files showing as not found on console and not rendering immediately on page load

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, fonts

I have a fonts folder where I have included font files to the font `lemonmilk`:

[image]

I'm having two issues at the moment:

1. Upon inspecting console, I get the following 404 error: `/fonts/lemonmilk-medium.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`
2. When loading the page, the font family doesn't load in immediately, it changes to the correct font once the page has loaded.

To address issue 2, I've tried to add `font-display` and `unicode-range`, but still seeing the same results.

Here is how I've defined the `font-face`:

```
$font-families: (
  'lemonmilk-regular': 'lemonmilk-regular',
  'lemonmilk-light': 'lemonmilk-light',
  'lemonmilk-medium': 'lemonmilk-medium',
  'lemonmilk-bold': 'lemonmilk-bold',
);

@each $key, $val in $font-families {
  @font-face {
    font-family: #{$key};
    src: url('../fonts/#{$val}.eot');
    src:  url('../fonts/#{$val}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('../fonts/#{$val}.woff') format('woff'),
          url('../fonts/#{$val}.woff2') format('woff2'),
          url('../fonts/#{$val}.ttf') format('truetype'),
          url('../fonts/#{$val}.svg#sansationregular') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
    unicode-range: U+00-FF;
  }
}
```

The font files exist so unsure why it's giving me a 404 error, and I'm unsure on how to optimise the font load speed further?

Answer (score 0):

### About HTML File Paths

The following hypothesis is based on having your `style.css` file in the Wordpress theme root directory.

> `style.css` should reside in the root directory of your theme not within the CSS directory. [...]

*Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/organizing-theme-files/#theme-folder-and-file-structure*

Your problem seems to be coming from the fact that you're are asking your css file to search for your font in the wrong directory.

> A file path describes the location of a file in a web site's folder structure.
>
> - `<img src="picture.jpg">` = The "picture.jpg" file is located in the same folder as the current page.
> - `<img src="images/picture.jpg">` = The "picture.jpg" file is located in the images folder in the current folder.
> - `<img src="/images/picture.jpg">` = The "picture.jpg" file is located in the images folder at the root of the current website.
> - `<img src="../picture.jpg">` = The "picture.jpg" file is located in the folder one level up from the current folder.

*Source @ https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp*

**CURRENTLY** you're trying to look for your font file in the "folder one level up from the current folder" (4th case scenario). You need to look for your font "at the root of the current website" (3rd case scenario). the only thing you probably have to do is changing the double-dot dash `../` by a simple dash `/`.

- **Right way** = `url('/fonts/#{$val}.eot');`.
- **Wrong way** = <s>`url('../fonts/#{$val}.eot');`.</s>

---

### About optimizing webfonts loading and rendering:

**1.** The browser begins parsing the HTML response and constructing the DOM.
**2.** The browser discovers CSS, JS, and other resources and dispatches requests.
**3.** The browser performs layout and paints content to the screen. After the font is available, the browser paints the text pixels.
*(This concise version of what's happening)*

By default, the font is only displayed after the HTML as started to be parsed and the css file have been found. We want the font to be parsed at the same time as the HTML, to do that we need to move our font loading request in the `<head>` tag in our `header.php` and ask our browser to preload our font using `<link rel="preload">`.

> The preload value of the `<link>` element's rel attribute lets you
> declare fetch requests in the HTML's `<head>`, specifying resources that
> your page will need very soon, which you want to start loading early
> in the page lifecycle, before browsers' main rendering machinery kicks
> in. This ensures they are available earlier and are less likely to
> block the page's render, improving performance.

*Source @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content*

Finally, I would highly recommend using CDNs and maybe a font library like [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/). In short, Google Fonts lets websites cross-share fonts across any and all websites using Google Fonts (millions) by saving it on the user's browser.

if a user visit a website called `website 1` using a font called `font 1` hosted on [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/), that user is going to automatically download it and store it. Upon visiting a `website 2` using `font 1` from Google Font, the font load will be instantaneous.